# how to update my Ionic App Lib Version?

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, bower

In My Project, ionic info command here

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Ionic Version: 1.2.4-nightly-1917
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.5.1-beta.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68

I want to update my Ionic App Lib Version. from 0.5.1-beta.0 to 0.6.4

How Can I Do? ionic lib update and ionic lib update -d command not working!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**use this command :**

```
 npm install ionic-app-lib --save
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this command:

```
ionic lib update
```

This should automatically detect the latest stable setup for the overall environment and update to it.
Off course it asks and confirms eg like this :

*Are you sure you want to replace \stMobile\www\lib\ionic with an updated version of Ionic?*

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this:

```
bower update
```

This will update everything if you use bower